# remove ui mask on input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui

I have a ui-mask on a form field for a bank account number. Since we are a Belgian company The format for a bank account number will rarely change. That's why we chose to use ui-mask. In the case of when we hire a foreign employee it can be that his bank account number has a different format. Is there any way I can first check the first two characters (which are the country codes) and then apply a mask on the field?

EDIT: I have tried to use a JQuery input eventlistener so that when the user inputs data it checks if the input starts with "BE". If it doesn't then i remove the ui-mask attributes from the input field but it doesn't seem to work. It still displays the mask

```
$('#bankAccountNumber').on('input', function() {
    var countryCode = $(this).val();
    if ((!stringStartsWith(countryCode, "BE")) || (!stringStartsWith(countryCode, "B"))) {
        $(this).removeAttr("ui-mask");
        $(this).removeAttr("ui-mask-placeholder");
        $(this).removeAttr("ui-mask-placeholder-char");
    }
});

function stringStartsWith(str, prefix) {
    return str.slice(0, prefix.length - 1) === prefix;
}
```